# How to trigger a GitHub Action workflow for every successful commit

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-api, continuous-deployment

I want to run a GitHub Actions workflow for every successful commit (e.g. after all check suites have ran successfully).

It seems like the [check_suite](https://developer.github.com/v3/checks/suites/) events will be fired for each individual check suite, and contain no information about the other suites. I want to wait for all registered check suites.

The [status](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/) event seems to be exactly what I want:

> Statuses can include a context to indicate what service is providing that status. For example, you may have your continuous integration service push statuses with a context of ci, and a security audit tool push statuses with a context of security. You can then use the combined status endpoint to retrieve the whole status for a commit.

But the `status` lives completely unrelated to the `check_suites` events, and most CI services now uses the `check_suites` (including GitHub Actions itself), and not `status`.

How can I, with a GitHub Actions workflow, check that all check_suites finished and the commit has successfully passed all checks and tests?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GitHub API to list the check suites belonging to a ref: https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/#octokit-routes-checks-list-suites-for-ref.

So, within your action (triggered by `check_suite`), you can list all the suites for the current ref, check they're all successful and then run your code.

If you're building a javascript action it could look like this:

```
import * as github from "@actions/github";

const response = await client.checks.listSuitesForRef({
  owner: github.context.repo.owner,
  repo: github.context.repo.repo,
  ref: sha
});

const passes = response.data.check_suites.every(...)

if (passes) { ... }
```

The major drawback of this approach is that this very action is itself a check suite belonging to the current commit, so it will appear in `response.data.check_suites` (and will never be successful at this point ... because it's still running!). I don't have a solution for this part yet...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are now able to trigger actions based on commit `status` ([reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#status)).

```yaml
on:
  status
jobs:
  if_error_or_failure:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: >-
      github.event.state == 'error' ||
      github.event.state == 'failure'
    steps:
      - env:
          DESCRIPTION: ${{ github.event.description }}
        run: |
          echo The status is error or failed: $DESCRIPTION
```